ElasticSearch - Watcher search template action does not resolve variables in params
We are trying to use watchers in ElasticSearch 8.12.
In this example we want to pass variables from the simple input in the chain to the two searches below.
The first one is a standard search with a body and it works without problems.
The second one is a template search. When passing the variable to the params object, at runtime the variable is not resolved.
Is there a way to fix this kind of issue?
Thank you in advance!
"input": {
    "chain": {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "zero": {
            "simple": {
              "example_key": "value"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "first": {
            "search": {
              "request": {
                "indices": [
                  "example_index"
                ],
                "body": {
                  "size": 10,
                  "query": {
                    "match": {
                      "example_field": "{{ctx.payload.zero.example_key}}"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "second": {
            "search": {
              "request": {
                "indices": [
                  "example_index"
                ],
                "template": {
                  "id": "my-search-template",
                  "params": {
                    "example_field":"{{ctx.payload.zero.example_key}}",
                    "size": 10,
                    "from": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
      ]

